# This one's a kettle of (red) fish

Tags: steganography

> *Hell*o to all m*y* friends! And hello also to everyone in America,
>   England, India, and—well, and everywhere else where English (and http)
>   is spoken! If you don't know me yet, my nam*e* i*s* Rubio, a Moderator
>   serving Puzzling with [Gareth McCaughan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19114/gareth-mccaughan), [GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421/gentlepurplerain), and [Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi).
>   Right now I want to invite you (yes *...*.you!) to try to solve this evil
>   invention of mine, which nearly k*i*lled *m*y illustrious testing team of
>   solvers (and gave my f*a*ther a migraine)! So *p*rep*ar*e yourself t*o*
>   experience a puzzle that's (almost literally) to *die* for. You have to
>   name me. Yup, to solve this, just give my first and last name, that's all!

**What is my name?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's:

> Inigo Montoya

As buried in the text is:

> Hello my name is .... you killed my father prepare to die

These words are from:

> Each of the words with italics: "Hello" and "my" (line 1), "name" and "is" (line 3), "....you" (line 5), "killed" and "my" (line 6), "father" and "prepare" and "to" (line 7),  "die" (line 8).

Comment: Hopefully closer.

Comment: Duh.  It was there and I didn't copy it over.

Comment: And you've found my name, well done :)  Also, happy Easter and happy April Fools Day :)

Comment: I can't see a "you" in the expected form?

Comment: @IanF1 It's in there, if you know where to look. :)

Comment: @Rubio Methinks its time to submit a feature request for spoilering comments, rather than force all users to go through ROT-13.

Answer (score 12):

An extremist view of this puzzle yields

> a double acrostic.

Specifically,

> the first letters of each line spell out HE IS RISEN, and the last letters of each line spell out APRIL FOOL.

Because

> today is both Easter Sunday and April Fool's Day.

I suspect we haven't found all this puzzle's secrets yet ... in particular, I think there might be something more in

> the lengths, letters, or distributions of the words. Some of the sentences, even in the middle of lines (not affecting the acrostics), feel a bit clumsily worded, as if they're hiding something more than their immediate meaning.

Comment: True, but this is *not an answer* ... :)

Comment: @Rubio I wanted to say the requested first and last names could be the one who's risen, but more likely this is just another scarlet cod.

Comment: I truly believe I have seen this "HE IS RISEN" word somewhere in another answer... Or I dunno whether it was just *deja vu*...

Comment: Hu, ng yrnfg sbe zr, Rnfgre Fhaqnl vfa'g ba Ncevy 1 guvf lrne. *(ROT13)*

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος That's probably because you celebrate Orthodox Easter (I'm guessing from your Greek username), which is a week later than the Easter celebrated in the west.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Probably yeah, but shouldn't you clarify that? (bah, spoilers :P)

Answer (score 7):

Well, I can't find anything else, so...

> The italicized letters spell out *Hell yes... I'm a parodie(parody).*

Which could point to

> Ed Millband, who was(is?) famous for a catchphrase he said in an interview, "Hell yes I'm tough enough."

Comment: You've found a (poorly spelled) red herring, congratulations!

Comment: @Rubio Yeah, I thought so... I expect more depth out of this one, will keep looking :)

Answer (score 4):

I believe the biggest hint in the body of the puzzle is the words:

> my name is Rubio

Combined with the fact that

> the puzzle is posted under the account name of Rubio

And the fact that you ask for

> "my first and last *name*", not "*names*"

Which tells me that

> You have only one name which is both first and last

And that your name is therefore

> Rubio

Happy Easter and Happy April Fools' Day!

Comment: I've never been asked to give my first and last name***s***.

Comment: @Chowzen perhaps, but the wording does allow for my interpretation even if it doesn't require it. Anyway the correct answer has arrived now - thanks for reading mine!

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's just another smoked kipper, like the italicized parodies, but who knows, at least this contains a real first name:

> The last letters of the lines spell "April Fool".

Comment: [Someone else got there first ...](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63157)

Answer (score 0):

my contribution (probably coincidence but who knows):

> taking a rot13 of the first letters of all the words in parentheses, one gets "**null**ntzsnzny"

Also:

> the first letters of the sentences spell out "**hairs**yy"

Comment: My gods, null hair! Rubio is balding!

Comment: Mange?!?!  aaiiieieeee!  (I'll confirm these words appearing in this way is pure coincidence.)

Answer (score 0):

Reading just

> the words preceding an exclamation point (and allowing for the exclusion of words in brackets, except where the exclamation point is within the brackets) you get `friends, spoken, you, solvers, all`.

-

> It is a leap but, could it be Puzzling Solver?

Besides that, I am tempted to throw wild guesses based on the acrostic.